# Optimize random query in search engine

Tags: search, search-engine

I am trying to create a website which returns a random interesting website. The way I am doing this is I am creating a large word pool (over 10,000 words) randomly selecting several words out of it and then sending them in to a search engine (Bing, Google etc...).

The original word pool words will be ranked by the users of the website by their ranking of the website they are given and then bad words will be removed from the word pool. Some more optimization after the result of the first query will be done on the returned set of websites to select the best website from them.

What I need for this to work from the beginning is a descent list of words which are good and will give many results also when paired with other words. Is there a place where I can find a large list of words that will return better websites?

So, what I am looking for is a (very large) list of words optimized for searches, anyone got ideas?

Maybe if someone has good way of creating random queries that would be good too, because simply selecting 3 random english words does not create a good query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a google search for 'english wordlists download'

http://www.net-comber.com/wordurls.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: It looks ok, but i'm looking for more search oriented words... i've already got a pretty big list of words there just too specific and not generic enough to be put together for a nice search query...

Comment: So either the words retrieved are too general, or per @sinha 's msg, they're too repetitive. You either have a manual task ahead of you selecting from the word lists or you can rely on the google(like) output. OR Do you know shell programming? `sort file1 file2 file3 | uniq > allUniqWords` might be a place to start. Then do a script that randomly selects words? ELSE do as sinha suggests and apply same uniqueifing process to that output. If you come up with a better solution, please post the answer and give yourself the green checkmark ;-) ! Good luck.

Comment: the problem with @sinha 's answer is that those words are not really that good, they are mainly (as i told him) Google, Facebook and other famous and very big websites. The problem is not that i can't "uniqify" the results but that i think that when I do so I will be left with only 10 unique results. Your answer was a bit better, bigger lists of words, still it didn't totally solve the problem, which is, when choosing a query from the list, the results are not of great quality. this may be the best option I have but I would like to wait a little longer to see if I can get a better answer.

Comment: Rereading your question, I think you're looking for bi and tri-grams (2 and 3 word sets), right? Looked at the output from `../insights/search/#`, while the are multi-word targets, I see what you mean, difficult! The challenge is then to find a source of 2 and 3 word groupings that might be found in search queries. A much more difficult problem. Maybe Yahoo or a smaller commercial search engine has access to full text of queries submitted. Then uniqifying that output. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of words optimized for searches, you can use http://www.google.com/insights/search/# and call it iteratively for each date in say last 2 years.

Comment: problem is, it gives a very small amount of words, im looking for a much larger pool of words...

Comment: That should not be a problem as you can use the advanced options to get various results and (as I said before) call it iteratively for different date-ranges, again and again (using something like HttpUnit) to get big list that you want.

Comment: still I'm looking for 10,000 words at least, and most of these words are the same and very specific like google, ipod, firefox, microsoft...